# Realize click_and_crop in a class

Tags: python, class, events, onclick, mouse

```
refPT = []
def click_and_crop(event, x, y, flags, param):
    global refPt
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        refPT = [x, y]
        print(f"Location=({refPT})")
        cv2.waitKey(500)
```

The above code works for me out side a class. But is it possible to realized it in a class to combine other class variables, e.g. self.scale, in calculation?

```
def click_and_crop(self, event, x, y, flags, param):
    global refPt
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        refPT = [x, y] * self.scale
        print(f"Location=({refPT})")
        cv2.waitKey(500)
```

In the class which calls click_and_crop, I have something like below. and this class has self.scale

```
cv2.namedWindow("Image")
cv2.setMouseCallback("Image", click_and_crop)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
refPT = []

class Handler:

    def __init__(self, scale=1):
        self.scale = scale

    def click_and_crop(self, event, x, y, flags, param):
        global refPt
        if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
            refPT = [x * self.scale, y * self.scale]
            print(f"Location=({refPT})")
            cv2.waitKey(500)
        

hnd = Handler(scale=3)

def click_and_crop(event, x, y, flags, param):
    hnd.click_and_crop(event, x, y, flags, param)
```

Comment: So which click_and_crop shall I use with your code? I will call click_and_crop inside my class as I updated my post above. It seems a bit weird by these code, as I want to have a class to call click_and_crop, not click_and_crop to call a class.